# Issue in running sudo visudo command?

Tags: sudo

I get the following error when running `sudo visudo` on my Ubuntu:

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers busy ,try again later
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had you already run visudo ? That error indicates that the file is already being edited. First stop the other process with:

```
killall visudo
```

Also run

```
visudo -c
```

to make sure that the sudoers file was not corrupted.

Comment: It is not working:                                                                                              `mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> killall visudo`
`visudo(9348): Operation not permitted`
`visudo: no process found`
`mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> visudo -c`
`visudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied`
`mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> sudo visudo -c
/etc/sudoers: parsed OK`
`/etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK`
`mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> sudo visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers busy, try again later`
Still stuck with the same error.

Comment: What is the output for "ps -ef|grep sudo" on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

If the accepted answer not working for you, then you can try this:

List all processes that use sudo

```
ps -ef|grep sudo
```

then you should kill all process **id** that existed in the second columns, by using this command:

```
kill -9 YOUR_PROCESS_ID
```